# Show that $e^{\frac{3\ln(2+\sqrt3)\ln(2-\sqrt3)}{ 2\ln(2-\sqrt3)-\ln(2+\sqrt3)}}= 2 + \sqrt{3}$

Tags: arithmetic

How from $e^{\frac{3\ln(2+\sqrt3)\ln(2-\sqrt3)}{ 2\ln(2-\sqrt3)-\ln(2+\sqrt3)}}$ do I get $2+\sqrt{3}$?

This is a simple problem that I am unable to solve. I tried using properties of logarithms, but I cannot find $2+\sqrt{3}$, as Wolfram says... how can I do it?

Thanks.

Comment: I have a feeling that you might need the result
$$
\frac{1}{2+\sqrt{3}} = 2 - \sqrt{3}
$$
which leads to $\ln(2+\sqrt{3}) + \ln(2 - \sqrt{3}) = 0$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that, as [Matti P.](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/432405/matti-p)'s question [comment](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3634371/show-that-e-frac3-ln2-sqrt3-ln2-sqrt3-2-ln2-sqrt3-ln2-sqrt3/3634391#comment7469116_3634371) indicates, you have

$$(2+\sqrt{3})(2-\sqrt{3}) = 4 - 3 = 1 \implies 2-\sqrt{3} = (2+\sqrt{3})^{-1} \tag{1}\label{eq1A}$$

To make the algebra simpler, use

$$x = 2+\sqrt{3} \implies x^{-1} = 2-\sqrt{3} \tag{2}\label{eq2A}$$

The exponent of $e$ in your expression now becomes

$$\begin{equation}\begin{aligned}
\frac{3\ln(2+\sqrt3)\ln(2-\sqrt3)}{ 2\ln(2-\sqrt3)-\ln(2+\sqrt3)} & = \frac{3\ln(x)\ln(x^{-1})}{2\ln(x^{-1}) - \ln(x)} \\
& = \frac{3\ln(x)(-1)\ln(x)}{-2\ln(x) - \ln(x)} \\
& = \frac{-3\ln^2(x)}{-3\ln(x)} \\
& = \ln(x)
\end{aligned}\end{equation}\tag{3}\label{eq3A}$$

This now results in

$$\begin{equation}\begin{aligned}
e^{\frac{3\ln(2+\sqrt3)\ln(2-\sqrt3)}{ 2\ln(2-\sqrt3)-\ln(2+\sqrt3)}} & = e^{\ln(x)} \\
& = x \\
& = 2 + \sqrt{3}
\end{aligned}\end{equation}\tag{4}\label{eq4A}$$